# Finding a string in a jumbled string

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

Is there a function in Python 3 that would allow me to find a substring in any order in a larger string? For example:

```
ant in Gnat returns True
flat in plat returns False
cooler in polomacear returns True
```

Comment: You are probably meant to come up with something yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I whipped up that will do it.  There might be something easier, but it passes tests!

```
def check(sub, full):
    full_list = list(full)
    for char in sub:
        if char in full_list:
            full_list.remove(char)
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: For strings long enough for the O(n*n) behavior to matter, collections.Counter could be used on both strings. Then see if the sub multiset is a submultiset of the full multiset.